# Combine these 2 json objects released asynchronously into single json string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using node.js yahoo-finance module to retrieve Apple and Google stock prices. This works and the code is shown below.

```
var util = require('util');

require('colors');

var _ = require('lodash');
var yahooFinance = require('yahoo-finance');

var FIELDS = _.flatten([
    //symbol,name, lastTradeDate, lastTradePriceOnly,
    ['s', 'n', 'd1', 'l1']
]);

var SYMBOLS = [
    'AAPL',
    'GOOG',
];

yahooFinance.snapshot({
    fields: FIELDS,
    symbols: SYMBOLS
}).then(function (result) {
    _.each(result, function (snapshot, symbol) {            
        console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot, null, 2));
    });
});
```

The output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot, null, 2));` at the end looks like this;

```
{
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "name": "Apple Inc.",
  "lastTradeDate": "2015-11-03T16:00:00.000Z",
  "lastTradePriceOnly": 122
}
{
  "symbol": "GOOG",
  "name": "Alphabet Inc.",
  "lastTradeDate": "2015-11-03T16:00:00.000Z",
  "lastTradePriceOnly": 728.11
}
```

The problem is that it looks like json but it is still not a properly formatted json.

The desired json would look like this;

```
[{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "name": "Apple Inc.",
    "lastTradeDate": "2015-11-03T16:00:00.000Z",
    "lastTradePriceOnly": 122
},
{
    "symbol": "GOOG",
    "name": "Alphabet Inc.",
    "lastTradeDate": "2015-11-03T16:00:00.000Z",
    "lastTradePriceOnly": 728.11
}]
```

How can the code be changed to obtain the desired json output? This is tricky as each of the json object is released asynchronously task by task and not all at once.

Comment: Based on your code, `result`is already an array, try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` and this is what you expected.

Comment: @ ojovirtual, thank you. It almost works. Still need some adjustment. let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from ojovirtua, I found the answer.

```
yahooFinance.snapshot({
    fields: FIELDS,
    symbols: SYMBOLS
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```